# Why can't I get all elements and add a class to them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, I am trying to do something, but I am clearly doing it wrong.

I have this function in JS:

```
function onFocus() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('blur').classList.add("blurry");
    }

    function onFocusOut() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('blur').classList.remove("blurry");
    }
```

The error I ge, is as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

What I try to do, is to get all elements with the classname *blur* and add another classname *(blurry)* to it... yet this doesn't work, because my CSS is not being changed.

The only thing I want to achieve, is to add opacity to the elements with that classname when an input field is clicked / focused and to remove it when someone clicks outside of the input field.

```
.blurry {
  opacity: 0.4
}
```

**PS:** initially, I started using `id's` instead of `classes`, but that would mean that I can use this function just on one HTML elements. That's why I decided to switch to classnames.

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array. And arrays don't have the `classList` property, so it is `undefined`. So it can't read the method/property `.add()` of `undefined`

Comment: Oh... didn't know that. What should I use instead of an classList, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain that format you're going for, you can simply add a `for` loop to iterate through all of the elements with the class name "blur".

I've added an example of a way to implement a `for` loop in your case:

```
function onFocus() {
    var blurElements = document.getElementsByClassName('blur');
    for (var i = 0, l = blurElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        blurElements[i].classList.add("blurry");
    }
}

function onFocusOut() {
    var blurElements = document.getElementsByClassName('blur');
    for (var i = 0, l = blurElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        blurElements[i].classList.remove("blurry");
    }
}
```